# How to check python version that vim was compiled with?

Tags: python, vim

In the terminal, it works to do

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.version)"
```

but doing

```
:python -c "import sys; print(sys.version)"
```

in vim throws a SyntaxError.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I just discovered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872079/compiling-vim-with-specific-version-of-python) that you can also do it with

```
:python import sys; print(sys.version)
```

Comment: Use `:python3 import sys; print(sys.version)` if you have compiled Vim with python 3.

Answer (score 10):

I think you want this:

Type:

```
:python << EOF
import sys;
print(sys.version);
EOF
```

If vim was compiled with python, when you type `:python << EOF` in the command line, the command line will expand with newlines and wait for the EOF. Before the EOF, type your python code, and terminate with an EOF.

**Edit:** as you've already discovered, the `EOF` is unnecessary and you can have your script on a single line, sans quotes and `-c`. The EOF trick is nice for testing out python/VIM scripts in the command line.

```
:python import sys; print(sys.version);
```

Comment: +1. Of the answers so far, do you know if all of them use the version that vim was compiled with, as opposed to the system vim?

Comment: Not sure I follow you. All of what? Typing `:!anyCommand` in vim will invoke an external (system) command, e.g. `:!python`. `:python` (internal) will only be available if python scripting support has been compiled into vim.

Comment: Thanks, I was basically just asking which pythons `:!python` and `:python` referred to.

Comment: By the way, this worked with my *real* vim, but for some reason the newlines seem to be throwing off Macvim. (it prints them off as ^M)

Comment: ahh I see. Then I did follow you. I use MacVim also and the `<< EOF` has never showed `^M`.

Answer (score 10):

Run [`:ve[rsion]`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#:version) in [command-line mode](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Learning_the_vi_Editor/Vim/Modes#command-line) or run [`vim --version`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/vi) from [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)).

1. If [`vim`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)) was compiled **with Python 3**, you'll find `-python` and `+python3`.
2. If [`vim`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)) was compiled **with Python 2**, you'll find `+python` and `-python3`.
3. If [`vim`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)) was compiled **without Python** support, you'll find `-python` and `-python3`<sup>1</sup>.

I'm not sure if it's possible to find both `+python` and `+python3` in [`:ve`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#:version) output –
currently **[probably not](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/779/how-do-i-get-vim-to-be-able-to-run-both-python-and-python3-on-a-linux-system-in)**.

---

<sup>1</sup>Currently `-python` and `-python3` [seem](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10242/vim-8-0-python-support) to be the default for the [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) [`vim` package](https://packages.debian.org/sid/vim). If you need [`vim`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)) support for scripting languages, install [`vim-nox`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/vim-nox), which is dedicated to them and therefore has (among other things) `+python3` enabled. There is also an interesting, heavily refactored [`vim`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)) fork called [`neovim`](https://neovim.io/) (or [`nvim`](https://neovim.io/) in short). BTW: on [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) you can list all installed [`vim`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)) versions by running [`update-alternatives --list vim`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives).

Comment: On Mac I see +python/dyn and +python3/dyn but Python3 plugin Black fails and during start up vim display "This script requires ... Python 3.6 support"

Answer (score -3):

You could just run a `python --version` from within Vim directly:

1. Open vim.
2. In normal mode (NOT insert mode), type `:!python --version`.
3. Type enter.

The version of python is displayed.

Comment: This is an incorrect answer. This runs the external python command and displays the version of that, NOT of what vim was compiled with.